# forever cannot find .js files on windows 2008 x64

Tags: windows, node.js, forever

```
var forever = require('forever-monitor');

var panel = new (forever.Monitor)('p.js');
panel.start();
```

this code outputs :

```
events.js:72
   throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
          ^
Error: spawn ENOENT
    at errnoException (child_process.js:980:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:771:34)
```

at first i thought my code has a problem so i installed forever globally and tried

```
forever p.js
```

and it says

```
C:\w>forever p.js
warn:    --minUptime not set. Defaulting to: 1000ms
warn:    --spinSleepTime not set. Your script will exit if it does not stay up for at least 1000ms

events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: spawn ENOENT
    at errnoException (child_process.js:980:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:771:34)
```

while node p.js in the same directory works just fine , the file is there

when trying to run a non-existent file forever gives a different error message

any clues on where to look is appreciated .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try with C:\w>forever -c node p.js

was the fix to my problem...